# Why is this code giving "runtime error" in URI Online Judge

Tags: python-3.x, uri

I'm studying python by myself, and as i learn any topic, I go to URI Online Judge to solve some problems and practice my knowledge. In this problem (https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1235) I can't find what is getting me runtime error in my code. Can someone help me please?

```
import math

cases = int(input())
for i in range(0, cases):
    main_string = input()
    middle = int(math.trunc(len(main_string)/2))
    string1 = main_string[0:middle]
    string1 = string1[::-1]
    string2 = main_string[-1:middle-1:-1]
    print(f'{string1}{string2}')
```

Comment: what exactly does the message say?

Comment: When I submit, it only gives me 'runtime error'. But URI defines this as 'Typical error when you define a vector or array with less capacity than what is required for the problem, or when you try to access an invalid position in memory.'

Comment: does it not say anything else such as line number?

Comment: what kind of system are you running this on?

Comment: No, it won't give me a line number, just the error. URI compiles and run by itself... All i get is this [link](https://imgur.com/a/GXKtTg2)

Comment: are you entering and running the code on your own computer or on a web site?

Comment: you need to install real Python on your own computer and then use it to run your code so you can debug it before submitting it on the web site.  this is so you get the real error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code on my local machine with Python 3.7.3, and it works. You use `f-string` while printing, and it is a feature for the Python versions after 3.6, take a look at [this link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#raw-f-strings) or [this](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). URI Online Judge is using Python 3.4.3, so it is not supported on the website. Just replace your print line with this and try again:

```
print(string1 + string2)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot, i didn't notice that URI is using an older version!!